The GET method is not supported for route new-order-form. Supported methods: POST. LARAVEL
Please help me! I don't know where am I wrong?
web.php:
Route::post('new-order-form', [OrderController::class, 'showNewOrderForm'])->name('new.order.form');

OrderController.php:
public function showNewOrderForm()
    {
        $products = SanPham::all();
        $employees = Employee::all();
        return view('order.new_order_form', compact('products', 'employees'));
    }

/order/new_order_form.blade.php
/order/order.blade.php:
$(document).ready(function(){
            // Hiển thị form tạo đơn hàng mới khi click
            $("#newOrderBox").click(function(){
                window.location.href = "{{ route('new.order.form') }}";
            });
});

I tried replacing GET, POST, PUT but it didn't work.

Well, Route::post only allows POST requests, if you want to allow 'GET' requests you would use Route::get.

should have try any
Route::any('new-order-form', [OrderController::class, 'showNewOrderForm'])->name('new.order.form');

$(document).ready(function(){
            // Hiển thị form tạo đơn hàng mới khi click
            $("#newOrderBox").click(function(){
                window.location.href = "{{ route('new.order.form') }}";
            });
});

if you have same function for view get and post you should try any method to achieved it
Route::any('new-order-form', [OrderController::class, 'showNewOrderForm'])->name('new.order.form');

$(document).ready(function(){
            // Hiển thị form tạo đơn hàng mới khi click
            $("#newOrderBox").click(function(){
                window.location.href = "{{ route('new.order.form') }}";
            });
});


Route::get('new-order-form', [OrderController::class, 'showNewOrderForm'])->name('new.order.form');

or use get if want to get only
Route::get('new-order-form', [OrderController::class, 'showNewOrderForm'])->name('new.order.form');


Route::get('new-order-form', [OrderController::class, 'showNewOrderForm'])->name('new-order-form');


window.location.href = "/new-order-form";

